# How can I include all of the C++ Standard Library at once?

Tags: c++, templates, std

I am working on a class project using vectors and linked lists. But in C++, in order to apply them, I need to have the following code in my header.

```
#include<list>
#include<vector>
```

I know that both of these are a part of the standard template library. So I'd like to do a single

```
#include<StandardTemplateLibrary>
```

to save lines. But everywhere I look I don't see a single command to add to my code. I've tried cstdlib, stdlib, and cstdlib.h, and none of them contain the keywords I need.

Is there a single preprocessor that I can add to my project to do both of these? Or do I just have to include both? If you can refer me to source to read as well that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is "saving lines" important?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to `include` the whole library, most of which your code does not even use.

Comment: To extend the previous comment: because it will slow down compilation significantly (of course depending on how fast your computer is).

Comment: Related: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3425536)

Comment: No real reason @BartFriederichs it just seems like it'd be easier to call functions that I may need later if I just include the whole thing instead of including it in pieces. But I couldn't find `<bits/stdc++.h>` anywhere I looked. Either I suck at research or I came to the right place.

Comment: StandardTemplateLibrary is certainly the wrong name.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am most certainly aware. I included that to express the idea of what I'm trying to go for. This question gave me lots of feedback on how to use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and that it is a compiler related header that shouldn't be used because it does add to compile time by alot by adding a ton of un-needed info. Saving keystrokes isn't the best way to program, its creating error free light complexity code. I learned quite a bit but for some reason I got 3 downvotes. :-( I don't know if I asked a bad question or if it's just hatred for `bits/stdc++.h` XD

Comment: @Hikari - my point was about the **meaning** of "StandardTemplateLibrary**, not its length. C++ has a **standard library**. It does not have a **standard template library**. STL was adopted as **part** of the standard library. It did not swallow it.

Comment: "How can I include all of the C++ Standard Library at once?" - Don't. Why would you want to? You'll just increase your build times needlessly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On some compilers, including `<bits/stdc++.h>` might do what you're looking for.

Note however that it makes your code nonportable (it may not work on other compilers, or even different versions of the same compiler). This is ok in some cases.

More info about why doing this might not be a good idea: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3425536)

Comment: Please don't *ever* recommend or advice including `bits/stdc++.h`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

as even suggested by everyone. **But it is not a standard header file.**
The disadvantages of it are that it

- increases the compilation time. (As it includes all the header files together)
- uses an internal non-standard header file of the GNU C++ library, and so will not compile in [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), and many other compilers

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a singular preprocessor that I can add to my project to do both of these? Or do I just have to include both?

No there isn't and that's intentional. The standard library implementation should have a minimum of inter dependencies for the implemented components.

You should always specify the `#include` statements for the `std` components you use explicitly.

---

And don't be tricked by the infamous [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Out of curiosity: why is this intentional?

Comment: @BartFriederichs To minimize dependencies.

Comment: This is a useless answer for the OP if you don't explain why it is intentional and why you should ALWAYS specify the includes for what you use explicitly and why the OP shouldn't be tricked by the infamous include. You are fully right, but if you don't explain why, it is hard to learn anything from this post.

Comment: @Chiel The disadvantages of `#include <bits/stdc++>` are well explained in the linked post.

Comment: One of the principles of C++ is "you shouldn't pay for stuff you don't use"; i.e. the presence of additional features in the language shouldn't add overhead to your program unless you're actually using those features in your program.  Having a single "everything" header-file would go against that principle, since that file would get larger (and slower to process, and take up more RAM) every time anything new was added to the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

Rejoice! [C++23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B23) shall save you effort of including everything. You can just do:

```cpp
import std; // Imports everything in the 'std' library
import std.compat; // Brings the C library to the global namespace
```

Although you may need to wait for a year or three for compilers to support it.

Comment: What is unjoyful is that the current C++20 module support (G++ 13.2) is too buggy and unusable. Worse, it doesn’t even support `import std;`.

Answer (score 4):

Include lots of unused headers will drastically increase build time! Add only needed files

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a pre-compiled-header file for yourself of often included to speed up builds. It was popular last millennium.

[See this Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#ifndef ALL_H_FILES
#define ALL_H_FILES

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
//include other libraries

#endif
```

On your main file, you can: #include "ALL_H_FILES.h"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including different libraries for different functions you can simply just add

```html
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

at the top of your cpp program.